# In Rails 4 how do I write code that will retrieve objects instead of active record relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have this code:

```
Sectionheader.where(:doc_id => @doc_id)
```

which returns:

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation 
[#<Sectionheader id: 1, section_id: nil, content: "a15+,f15+,a15+,f15+,a15+,f15+,a15+,f15+", created_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", updated_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", documentname: nil, doc_id: 1, row_number: 3, mergedsectionheader_id: nil>, 
    #<Sectionheader id: 2, section_id: nil, content: "A50+,F50+,A50+,F50+,A50+,F50+,A50+,F50+", created_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", updated_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", documentname: nil, doc_id: 1, row_number: 12, mergedsectionheader_id: nil>,
```

This result set is an array of activerecord relation objects. How can I instead get objects of type Sectionheader?

There used to be this method but it seems its been deprecated in rails 4
     example this will return an array of person objects.

```
Person.find(1, :conditions => "administrator = 1", :order => "created_on DESC")
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

Comment: `Sectionheader.where(:doc_id => @doc_id).to_a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergio Tulentsev commented above.

If you want to get an array of Sectionheader records from a relation, you can call #to_a

```
Sectionheader.where(:doc_id => @doc_id).to_a
```

If you wanted to eager-load the relation, you can call #load

```
Sectionheader.where(:doc_id => @doc_id).load
```

If you wanted to skip AR model instantiation completely, you could call #pluck(col1, col2, ...). This will return a multi-dimentional array representing the records.

```
Sectionheader.where(:doc_id => @doc_id).pluck(:id, :section_id, :content)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually have is a relation object representing your result set. If you were to perform an operation on it which required actual data from the database, it would resolve into an array style object. You can see this in action in the response, where the console is showing you actual data.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation 
[#<Sectionheader id: 1, section_id: nil, content: "a15+,f15+,a15+,f15+,a15+,f15+,a15+,f15+", created_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", updated_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", documentname: nil, doc_id: 1, row_number: 3, mergedsectionheader_id: nil>, 
    #<Sectionheader id: 2, section_id: nil, content: "A50+,F50+,A50+,F50+,A50+,F50+,A50+,F50+", created_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", updated_at: "2014-08-13 18:18:39", documentname: nil, doc_id: 1, row_number: 12, mergedsectionheader_id: nil>, ...
```

What this actually means is that `#<ActiveRecord::Relation` is the container. `[` shows that an array type object has been opened. `#<Sectionheader id: 1, ...` is the first element of the array, and so on.

If you hadn't ended your statement there (dumping it to the console and forcing ActiveRecord to make the query) you would have a relation object representing the SQL of your query. You could add to this (with a select, or conditions or ordering etc.) if you wished without incurring the penalty of further database look-ups.

For most situations you can (and probably should) just treat this as an array. You can do a `.to_a` on the relation if your normal array methods aren't working, or `.attributes` on a single object to get a hash of the values returned by the query.

For example, you could do:

```
Sectionheader.where(:doc_id => @doc_id).each do |sectionheader|
  puts sectionheader.doc_id
end
```

quite happily.